# Trying to Read an XML String Into a VB.NET DataTable

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I have an XML string based on the following...

```
<imsapi>
<status>0</status>
<statusmessage>Login OK</statusmessage>
<zoneresponse>
    <tasks>
        <task>
            <contact>
                <surname>Last Name</surname>
                <givennames>First Name</givennames>
                <userid>JScqTyVQXFwgCg==</userid>
            </contact>
            <contactname>User Name</contactname>
            <org>
                <orgid>JScqTyVRXFQgCg==</orgid>
                <orgname>Business Unit Name</orgname>
            </org>
            <requestdatetime>2019/06/26 08:56:09</requestdatetime>
            <status>Not Started</status>
            <readtaskdatetime>2019/07/04 12:44:08</readtaskdatetime>
            <description>Job description goes here...</description>
            <custon>INTERNAL</custon>
            <duedate>2020/01/13</duedate>
            <lastupdated>2020/01/06</lastupdated>
            <jobnumber>2387</jobnumber>
            <duedatetime>2020/01/13 00:00:00</duedatetime>
            <client>
                <clientid>JScqTyVRXFQgCg==</clientid>
                <clientname>Client Name</clientname>
            </client>
            <taskname>Job Name</taskname>
            <taskid>JiYqUyVRPEslCg==</taskid>
            <lastupdateddatetime>2020/01/06 10:39:44</lastupdateddatetime>
            <requestdate>2019/06/26</requestdate>
            <tasktype>Manufacturing Order</tasktype>
            <substatus>
                <substatusid>IyZaVywK</substatusid>
                <substatus>Not Started</substatus>
            </substatus>
        </task>
      </tasks>
    </zoneresponse>
</imsapi>
```

And I am loading the XML string into a dataset to load into a vb.net datagrid. When I run my code I am getting an error `Child list for field task cannot be created` and I can't figure out what would be causing this and how to resolve it.

My loading code is...

```
dim ds as new DataSet()
ds.ReadXML(New System.IO.StringReader(xmlString))
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
DataGridView1.DataMember = "task"
```

The XML is loading from the web server correctly as I can output it to a text field without any issue, it is only having an issue when I attempt to load it into the datagridview while defining that the task items are what I want to display.

Comment: The ReadXml does not work on xml files with more than 4 levels of tags.  When you have more than 4 levels of tags you get a DataSet with fragmented tables that cannot be recombined.  So you have to parse the xml with other Net libarary methods.  I can help if you need support.

Answer (score 3):

are you missing a closing "tasks" tag?

I'm no xml expert so I used an xml checker and got:

> An error has been found!
>   Errors in the XML document:
>       40: 7   The element type "tasks" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "

hope that helps.

Comment: I have added the missing tasks tag which was on the source XML string but I just missed when copying and anonymizing the string for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you posted **IS** invalid, it is missing the ending tag for **tasks**.  Once I fixed the XML the following code ran.  Don't know that it produces what you expect.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'you could replace the literal assignment with
    '   xe = XElement.Load("path here")
    xe = <imsapi>
             <status>0</status>
             <statusmessage>Login OK</statusmessage>
             <zoneresponse>
                 <tasks>
                     <task>
                         <contact>
                             <surname>Last Name</surname>
                             <givennames>First Name</givennames>
                             <userid>JScqTyVQXFwgCg==</userid>
                         </contact>
                         <contactname>User Name</contactname>
                         <org>
                             <orgid>JScqTyVRXFQgCg==</orgid>
                             <orgname>Business Unit Name</orgname>
                         </org>
                         <requestdatetime>2019/06/26 08:56:09</requestdatetime>
                         <status>Not Started</status>
                         <readtaskdatetime>2019/07/04 12:44:08</readtaskdatetime>
                         <description>Job description goes here...</description>
                         <custon>INTERNAL</custon>
                         <duedate>2020/01/13</duedate>
                         <lastupdated>2020/01/06</lastupdated>
                         <jobnumber>2387</jobnumber>
                         <duedatetime>2020/01/13 00:00:00</duedatetime>
                         <client>
                             <clientid>JScqTyVRXFQgCg==</clientid>
                             <clientname>Client Name</clientname>
                         </client>
                         <taskname>Job Name</taskname>
                         <taskid>JiYqUyVRPEslCg==</taskid>
                         <lastupdateddatetime>2020/01/06 10:39:44</lastupdateddatetime>
                         <requestdate>2019/06/26</requestdate>
                         <tasktype>Manufacturing Order</tasktype>
                         <substatus>
                             <substatusid>IyZaVywK</substatusid>
                             <substatus>Not Started</substatus>
                         </substatus>
                     </task>
                 </tasks>
             </zoneresponse>
         </imsapi>

    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds.ReadXml(xe.CreateReader)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "task"
```

Comment: I have just updated the question with the missing closing tasks tag. It is in the source XML string that I was working with but I unfortunately missed it when copying and anonymizing the XML string to put into the question. I have tried defining the XML string as XElement before loading the XML string or working with the dataset and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @ChrisRutherfurd-Did you try the code I posted?  It did work on my machine.

Comment: Yes I tried, I passed the variable which holds the XML obtained from the `webClient.DownloadString` method into XE but got an error back saying value of type String can not be converted to XElement so I have been trying to research how to parse a string into an XElement.

Comment: @ChrisRutherfurd - did you try XElement.parse  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse?view=netframework-4.8  ?